# Upgrading to Python 3.6.1 seems to have corrupted/broken modules

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, opensuse, python-3.6

Good day,

I recently tried to upgrade to Python 3.6.1 by building from source, and I've had a few issues.The first of which had to do with the $PYTHONHOME environment variable, which I have now (seemingly) solved, whereas the second - and most persistent - has to do with me not being able to access many modules.

For instance, when I launch the python3 interpreter, I immediately encounter an error that states:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/etc/pythonstart", line 7,
>   in 
>       import readline ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'readline'

Similar errors occur with other modules that are imported by other scripts, such as 'encodings'

> ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

and '_socket'

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_socket'

I'm not used to building from source, so I just used the instructions in the readme file that comes with the Python 3.6.1 tar ball, without much understanding of what's going on. I performed this procedure over and over again, (hopefully that didn't add to the problems), and here's the latest error output from the **make test** command:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "./Tools/scripts/run_tests.py", line 12, in 
>       import test.support
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/test/support/**init**.py", line 15, in
>   
>       import logging.handlers
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/handlers.py", line 26, in 
>       import logging, socket, os, pickle, struct, time, re
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 49, in 
>       import _socket ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_socket'
>    Makefile:1018: recipe for target 'test' failed make: *** [test] Error 1

I've searched all over the web frantically and I can't seem to find anything that really captures my problem, as the many other problems I've seen often involve people not being able to access only *one* module, or the solutions provided are extremely specific and seem difficult to generalise from (such as solutions that make use of lengthy Debian-based commands). I sincerely apologise if there are general solutions to this problem that I just haven't found.

Additionally, when I try to launch the Python 2 interpreter, I just get this error (and it fails completely):

> ImportError: No module named site

My system information:

1. OS: Opensuse Leap 42.2
2. Previous Python3 version: 3.4.5 Current
3. Python3 version: 3.6.1

Your help with this matter would be greatly, greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where did you build Python from source, and where did you take the source? Was it a distro-provided source package? Did you replace system-provided Python?

Comment: I hope you didn't do a sudo make install , that will have clobbered your system-provided python....

Comment: @irmen-de-jong Oh boy, this is exactly what I did. I just followed the instructions in the readme file :/

Comment: Hi @9000, I take it you're speaking about the directories? I initially just built it in my Downloads directory (where I had downloaded and extracted the tarball), and then I repeated the process in a new directory called "source" in my home folder. I did replace the system-provided Python, and this version of Python is one I downloaded from python.org - I think distro-provided only has 3.4.5 as the latest available version.

Comment: @armnod ouch. Glancing over the readme I think it could be well improved on this matter. You should have read on though, there's a section about installing multiple versions https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/README.rst#installing-multiple-versions